# Manipulate-able data table

Tags: c#, sql, database, user-interface, user-controls

I have requirements to implement a UI using c# where the user can manipulate what data they want to appear on a document. The data should enter the program via SQL (prefer not using Table Adapters as the database is then hardcoded into the program, but will use it if absolutely necessary).

The following UI will appear when the user chooses to enter a database table:

https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B6b_N7sDgjmvcUt2amxNaXpJRFU/edit?usp=sharing
https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B6b_N7sDgjmvdUhmMUJFbEdKeVk/edit?usp=sharing
https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B6b_N7sDgjmvM3BSWDEyM0ROOFE/edit?usp=sharing

- The user should be able to choose what columns (from all tables,
  connections should be made using PK/FK.)  they want to add to the
  table, and sort and move that data.
- The control should then able to generate the sql used to pull that
  information from the database (or even pass the database back to the
  main program, but prefer SQL)

I've seen this UI in many programs and would like to think there is a library out there that will save me the trouble of making this UI from scratch.

Are there any libraries available for C# that has this kind of functionality?

Comment: It sounds like you're looking for a report builder, or maybe Microsoft Access.

Comment: @JohnSaunders Funny you say that, that is the purpose of the program, but our users are not that IT literate so we have to build a UI that is extremely simple but powerful enough to be customizable.

Comment: Also our reports is meant to add multiple tables of this kind to one document, thus this interface.

Comment: Look at [Report Builder](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd220460.aspx) which is meant to be an end-user, not tech-savvy tool. It's like "Microsoft Word for Reports".

Comment: It would have been awesome if our users knew how to use Microsoft office  properly, The concepts of BI tools/databases are entirely new to them. If there are no third libraries available for this purpose, i may just have to roll my own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Telerik's [Rad Grid](http://www.telerik.com/products/aspnet-ajax/grid.aspx) will give you all of the functionality in terms of context menus and column reordering.  You wont be able to output the code needed to regenerate the table however.  You can export data directly from the grid using the column ordering specified in a range of formats (pdf, word, excel, etc.).

The Rad Grid is also not free, it is part of a suite of controls.

Answer (score 0):

You may also try [DevExpress](http://www.devexpress.com/). We use this control library for editing operations. It is not free but worth its price.